# FindCirclesGrid c++11 does not work though detector finds all points

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11

The Grid in the

[image]

is not found, though the `simpleBlobDetector` detects every blob.

I use the following code with image being the inputimage:

```
    vector<Point2f> pointBuf;
    Size gridSize(4, 11);

    cv::SimpleBlobDetector::Params params;
    params.maxArea = (image.rows * image.cols) / (gridSize.height * gridSize.width * 1.5);
    params.minArea = 70;
    params.minConvexity = 0.85;
    params.minThreshold = 80;
    params.maxThreshold = 230;
    params.thresholdStep = 20;
    params.minInertiaRatio = 0.05;

    auto detector = cv::SimpleBlobDetector::create(params);
    vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
    detector->detect(image, keypoints);

    Mat debugImage = Mat::zeros(image.size(), CV_8U);
    for (auto keypoint : keypoints) {
        drawKeypoints(debugImage, keypoints, debugImage, 255);
    }
    imwrite("./debug/" + "debugImage.png", image);
    imwrite("./debug/" + "debugImage2.png", debugImage);

    findCirclesGrid(image, gridSize, pointBuf, cv::CALIB_CB_ASYMMETRIC_GRID, detector);
```

The code works for other images. So why is the code not working on this image?

Comment: There are some undeclared parameters in the code you posted. Like: *pixels* and *debugIndex* can you add those parameters to your code

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your code and works fine. The only problem with the image you shared about the filter parameter `params.maxArea` This limit doesn't let the program to detect your grids. Here is the code I tried and the result:

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{

        Mat image = imread("/your/image/directory/blob.jpg");

        vector<Point2f> pointBuf;
        Size gridSize(4, 11);

        cv::SimpleBlobDetector::Params params;
        params.maxArea = 10000;
        params.minArea = 70;
        params.minConvexity = 0.85;
        params.minThreshold = 80;
        params.maxThreshold = 230;
        params.thresholdStep = 20;
        params.minInertiaRatio = 0.05;

        auto detector = cv::SimpleBlobDetector::create(params);
        vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
        detector->detect(image, keypoints);

        Mat debugImage = Mat::zeros(image.size(), CV_8U);
        for (auto keypoint : keypoints) {
            drawKeypoints(debugImage, keypoints, debugImage, 255);
        }

        findCirclesGrid(image, gridSize, pointBuf, cv::CALIB_CB_ASYMMETRIC_GRID, detector);

        imshow("Result",debugImage);
        imshow("Before",image);

        waitKey(0);
        return 0;

}
```

**The result:**

[image]

**Note:** *You can check [this documentation](https://www.learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/) to learn more about the parameters.*

Comment: My Blobdetector finds those exact points. But the Grid is not found. Is the maximal Size of the Grid also determined by the maxArea parameter for the findCirclesGrid method? Sorry I had to change my question, as I forgot to mention what pixels is (it was the number of pixels in the image).